# How to begin unit testing using phpstorm

Tags: php, unit-testing

so firstly, I am very new to coding. This question pertains to unit testing using php. Should be obvious, I know, but my question is, in order to actually use the unit tests i will eventually create, will I have to also make up some code apply the tests? All of the tutorials explain how to configure the IDE i am using (phpstorm) but do not give any sample code to actually perform the tests. Is there a feature built into phpstorm which allows you to try the unit tests you create? If i do in fact require sample code, what kind of code should i use and where could i get it from? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start testing, need to take some steps. It`s worked for ubuntu 18.04

- install php globally

  ```
  ~$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \  
     && sudo apt-get update \
     && sudo apt-get install -y php \
     && sudo apt-get install -y php-xml \
     && sudo apt-get install -y php-mbstring
  ```

  for checking installation success run `~$ php -v`
- install composer globally

  ```
  ~$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php'); " \  
   . "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === " \
   . "e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') " \
   . "{ echo 'Installer verified'; } " \
   . "else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" \
   && php composer-setup.php \
   && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
   && sudo mv composer.phar /bin/composer
  ```

  for checking installation success run `~$ composer -V`  (the relevant hash is always on [composer official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/download/))
- install phpunit - unit testing framework for php

  `project_folder$ composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit`

  this command will create `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files, also `vendor` directory at the root of your project.

---

Follow to some agreements I created two files - `Math.php` and `MathTest.php` and added autoload section to `composer.json`

Math.php

```
<?php  

namespace Source;  

class Math  
{  
     public function square($number)
     {
         return $number * $number;
     }
}
```

MathTest.php

```
<?php  

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;  
use Source\Math;  

class MathTest extends TestCase  
{  
     public $math;

     public function setUp(): void
     {
         $this->math = new Math();
     }

     public function testSquareEquals()
     {
         $this->assertEquals(4, $this->math->square(2));
         $this->assertEquals(16, $this->math->square(4));
     }

     public function testSquareNotEquals()
     {
         $this->assertNotEquals(3, $this->math->square(2));
         $this->assertNotEquals(9, $this->math->square(4));
     }
}
```

composer.json

```
{  
    "autoload": {  
        "psr-4": {  
            "Source\\": "src"  
        }  
    },  
    "require-dev": {  
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"  
    }  
}
```

the resulting project structure

```
project_folder  
├─── src  
│    └── Math.php  
├─── tests  
│    └── MathTest.php  
├── vendor  
├── composer.json  
└── composer.lock
```

to create autoload files:

```
project_folder$ composer dump-autoload
```

It`s all. Now you can start testing by running the command

```
project_folder$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```

```
PHPUnit 9.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 28 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB

OK (2 tests, 4 assertions)
```

where `tests` is the directory with your tests.

More examples in [phpunit official documentation](https://phpunit.de)

Comment: Great tutorial. We might note that these describe ONE way of doing things, but neither composer nor a globally installed php is strictly required.

Comment: Thank you @amlagoda I will read up on what these things mean because I honestly have no idea what these things are, or what the project_folder$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests command is actually testing for. I really appreciate you taking the time to post this tutorial, thanks again.

Comment: @AnthonyLopez Happy to help. Possible I can supplement this answer if there are more specific questions